# Why am I getting java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make a JAVA Applet to retrieve the user's MAC Address, convert it to MD5 and send it to a javascript function so it could do stuff.

I intent to append this MD5 to a form along some other inputed data.

So far I could retrieve the MAC address and convert it to MD5 successfully. What I could't do is to pass it to my javascript function.

This is my HTML code:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function dohash(hash) { alert(hash); }
    </script>
<APPLET code="start.class" width="200" height="200"></APPLET>
</body>
</html>
```

This is JAVA code:

```
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
import java.applet.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class start extends Applet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JSObject win;

    public void main() {
        win = (JSObject)JSObject.getWindow(this);
    }

    public void init() {
        InetAddress ip;
        String hashtext = "a";
        try {
            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

            NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));    
            }

                    try {
                            String plaintext = sb.toString();
                            MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                            m.reset();
                            m.update(plaintext.getBytes());
                            byte[] digest = m.digest();
                            BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1,digest);
                            hashtext = bigInt.toString(16);
                            while(hashtext.length() < 32 ){
                                hashtext = "0"+hashtext;
                            }
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        win.eval("alert('123');");
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SocketException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

This is the response on Eclipse's console:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at start.init(start.java:50)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:435)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with PHP and JavaScript?

Comment: I bet `line 50` is this one: `win.eval("alert('123');");` since it's in a `try catch` that catches `NPE`s.

Comment: Yes, line 50 is that win.eval...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`main` is not automatically invoked by the applet. Assign the `win` reference in the `init` method

```
public void init() {
    win = (JSObject)JSObject.getWindow(this);
    ...
}
```

Read: [Life Cycle of an Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html)

Comment: I've just tried this, and I think I has tried before... This throws the following error:`netscape.javascript.JSException
 at netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow(JSObject.java:180)
 at start.init(start.java:16)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:435)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)`

Comment: This exception _usually_ appears when running an applet with an IDE such as Eclipse. Did you try running it from a web browser?

Comment: That's what I thought. I compiled it with Eclipse and then I tried to run with Firefox 24.0 over a MacOSX 10.8.5. It doesn't return any error, but also doesn't run the alert('123')...

Comment: I actually tested this under Windows and it ran fine. Did you deploy the `plugin.jar` required for `JSObject`?

Comment: I set it over Eclipe, and also tried compile over the terminal with the following line `javac -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar start.java`

Comment: That's your compilation command. What about when the applet is being loaded by the browser? Is the `plugin.jar` available in the same location as the `start` class/jar?

Comment: I really don't know... How do I verify this? How would I make it available?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40273/discussion-between-reimeus-and-diego-riccio-trunx)